# Re-authenticating a user with Laravel Jetstream/Fortify

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I'm using Laravel Jetstream (which uses Laravel Fortify for authentication). The default behaviour seems to be that if a user is inactive for a period of time longer than the `SESSION_LIFETIME` in the `.ENV` file, the session expires.

I'm trying to modify how this session expiration is dealt with. Currently when a user  comes back to their computer to an expired session, if they click to navigate pages (e.g. any GET request) they'll be pushed back to the login page and are able to re-authenticate, which is great.

However the issue is that if they were in the middle of creating something like a blog post, which hasn't been saved yet, they become inactive for a longer period of time than `SESSION_LIFETIME` and their session expires, then they return to their computer, and continue adding to their blog post, when they try to save (a non-GET request) a 405 response (method not supported) is returned, and the user won't be able to save their post and will likely lose their work.

I essentially have two options here (1) set the `SESSION_LIFETIME` something like 2 weeks out so that this is unlikely to happen, or (2) create something like a modal that opens and allows the user to re-authenticate from their current page, thereby maintaining potentially unsaved data. Does anyone have experience with this? Most of the functionality seems to be from within `/vendor/laravel` folders so I'm not sure if it will be easy/worth it to change the functionality.

Thanks

Comment: Stale browser sessions are a pretty universal thing, and if your Users are leaving their browser open on webpages longer than a few minutes, encourage them to refresh the page on returning (much, _much_ easier said than done though). In the past, I've handled this with a JS timer that displays a Model after 2 hours of inactivity (`SESSION_LIFETIME` setting), but it said "Your browser session has expired. Please login again. Any work you had in progress will be lost." I'm not sure if there's an easy way to re-populate the session with a new expiry (depends on handler, file, database, etc)